# Exporting big liferay portal into LAR-file fails with no sensible error message

Tags: liferay

I'm using liferay portal community edition 6.1-

I'm trying to export a portal in order to move the content to another intance of liferay. however, when trying to export the portal content the export fails with message 'Your request failed to complete."

When looking at log files, there is no sign of anything going wrong.

Could someone please explain to me what can possibly be wrong, and from where should I get the information for what is failing on server?

---

Marko

Comment: It might be possible that the request timed out. Or you can change the log level for the LARExporter package and see what is happening and where it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging into similar issues with the LAR importing/exporting system myself. There isn't much logging in that code unfortunately. I ended up enabling remote debugging in the server's JVM and stepping through the problematic tasks using the Eclipse debugger.

One of the main issues I've had with Liferay is that it swallows detailed exceptions, doesn't log them, and waters them down into very generic error messages by the time they're displayed to you in the UI. Using the debugger really helps because you can often see the original exception without having to dig too deeply into the code.

How's your free disk space looking on the server? I believe Liferay saves the LAR to a temp file as it works on it (at least, it does as part of the publishing process). On our test site, with only ten pages and almost no content, that temp file is still 3.5M. If your site is really big you might just be running out of space.

Comment: The disc space seems to be quite adequate. I suspect something with timeouts. However, we ended up doing things manually, since the time to figure out this propblem started to look like eternity, and it only had to be done once.